# Query string parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^detail.html?id=([0-9]+)-page=([0-9]+)$ detail.php?id=$1&page=$2
```

I rewrite URL `detail.php?id=1&page=1` to `detail.html?id=1&page=1`. I always get the 404 errors.

Comment: Just to clarify, your code is rewriting from `detail.html` to `detail.php`, but your description that follows states the opposite?

Comment: detail.php to detail.html

Comment: Erm, are you sure? _Internally rewriting_ from `.php` to `.html` is not "normal". Or is this intended to be an _external redirect_? Which URL do you want to see in the browser's address bar - the one the user sees?

Answer (score 1):

You can't match the query string using `RewriteRule`. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, excluding the query string. You would need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against `%{QUERY_STRING}`. (So your directive never matches and you get a 404.)

However, it doesn't look like you need to match the query as you are simply rewriting the URL's "file" extension from `.html` to `.php`. Which could be done with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^detail\.html$ detail.php [L]
```

The query string is automatically copied to the destination URL (providing you don't explicitly specify one in the substitution).

You should also escape the dot (eg. `\.`) in the `RewriteRule` pattern (which is a regular expression), otherwise it will match *any character*.